# MVC ERROR Illegal characters in path.

Tags: asp.net-mvc

can someone tell me if im on the right track? Im trying to display my query but i get an error. I have two textbox with the same parameter and that parameter is declared as an IEnumerable.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Orders1(IEnumerable<int> order)
        {
            using (CostcoEntities1 context = new CostcoEntities1())
            {
                var query = string.Empty;

                foreach (var orderID in order)
                {

                        query = (from a in context.CM_Checkout_Details
                                 where a.CheckoutDetails_ID == orderID
                                 select a).ToString();
                }
                return View(query);
            }
        }
```

this is what my controller looks like..
I am trying to read the two numbers(Id) in the text box and diplay data based on those id.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Orders1", "Track", FormMethod.Post))
{
         @Html.TextBox("order")<br />
         @Html.TextBox("order")
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Comment: Note(another): query is `overwritten` inside foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Im trying to display the rows that match the id(order parameter). so how can i go about that if i dont want to overwrite the query? Thank you once again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, change the names of the textboxes so that they are not the same:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Orders1", "Track", FormMethod.Post))
{
         @Html.TextBox("order1")<br />
         @Html.TextBox("order2")
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Next, change the signature of your action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Orders1(string order1, string order2)
```

MVC's model binding will try to match order1 and order2 to stuff in Request.Form, for example, which should pick up the textbox values.

Comment: Thank for the response... but what if I wanted to create 10 textbox? I dont want to have 10 parameters.